# How to run an executable from assets/raw files in Android Nougat?

Tags: android, security, permissions, android-7.0-nougat

What is a correct way to run executable that is stored as asset or raw file in my android app in Android Nougat?

Comment: In the same way as with other versions. Why do you think its different?

Comment: yes, i'm sure it's different because of permissions, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578134/permission-denied-in-android-nougat-while-running-executable-from-app-directory

Comment: That link refers to executables on the file system, But your executable is in the assets or raw 'folder' of you packet. Please show your code running executables from assets that works on older versions.

Comment: assets = /data/data/package/assets directory in fs. The whole process building code is difficult, but i use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] command, String[] params, File workingDir)` at the end

Comment: You are trying to run an executable from private internal memory. Thats it! Not from assets resource.

Comment: eventually both assets and raw files are just files stored in fs so there is no difference, if you're trying to execute raw file or file in fs in app directory.

Comment: `eventually both assets and raw files are just files stored in fs `. Wrong. They are stored as resource.

Comment: what do you mean "as resource"? it's not jar file with resources. BTW jar is zip actually with `resources` folder and resource is file too

Comment: If you put, with your IDE, -executable-files in the assets directory then they are bound in the .apk as resources. They will not be normal files on the Android file system.

Comment: and what will they be? ;) let's be more specific, what will be raw files?

Comment: It is long time that you tell what you consider to be assets. And raw. And how your executables land in internal memory.

Comment: it does make sense if it's raw files or assets (read the question again). they will be in internal memory since the location of the app is set as internal in android manifest. Can you just answer what will be raw assets/raw files?

Comment: `they will be in internal memory since the location of the app is set as internal in android manifest`. Nonsense. That has nothing to do with assets or raw.

Comment: ok, the correct answer is: raw files will be raw files in app folder (in internal or external memory, does not make sense). i'm stopping waisting my time with you